# Unsubscribed from Simplenews Newsletter

Tags: users, emails

is there a way to find how many users unsubscribed from my Simplenews newsletter at my Drupal-7 website? And, if yes, can I detect from which particular newsletter did the user unsubscribe from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click admin/people/simplenews and check on status column.
OR
you can use following code to get the data

```
  // fetching from the database.
  $query = db_select('simplenews_subscriber', 'ss');
  $query->innerJoin('simplenews_subscription', 'si', 'si.snid = ss.snid');
  $query->fields('ss', array('mail'))
    ->condition('ss.activated', $condition_active)
    ->condition('si.status', $condition_subscribed)
    ->condition('si.newsletter_id', $newsletters)
    ->distinct();
  $data = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

where `si.status` is a flag indicating whether the user is **subscribed (1) or unsubscribed (0)**

and `$newsletters is a Array of newsletter ids to filter on`

Comment: thanks a lot! I was primarily looking for a SQL Query but I managed to track who unsubscribed based on your answer!